# Is there a way to show as text the value of a field of type Formula?

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a NotesNoteCollection containing the replication entries for a database. The field $ReplFormula is of type Formula (1536). Is there a way from a script using COM to convert that formula into a text representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a DXLexporter to convert the document to xml. Then you can read the formula from the resulting xml. There is no other way to do this

You can do this in memory by defining a stream as target for the export.